# bitbucket on mercurial freezes on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, push, bitbucket

I have been using github to keep my web site development updated with my designer. Until now everything worked fine until the folder exceeded 100MB. Github does not give me the opportunity to push my files any more.
I thought about turning to bitbucket+mercurial.
I am totally new to this but it looks like they workj the same way, but with not size restrictions.
So:
I have set up a repository in bitbucket.
I installed mercurial in Ubuntu.
Then i did `hg init` to initialize the folder.
Then i cloned my repository to my folder with `hg clone https://myrepositoryadress`
Then i copied all my files into this folder and then tried to commit them

```
hg commit -u myname -m "My first Commit"
```

then finally i want to push them with: `hg push https://myrepository adress`

At this point it asks me password and then freezes with the message:

```
searching for changes
```

The whole folder is about 140MB.
It doesnt show any action or like uploading anything it stays there forever.

Comment: Why would you switch to Mercurial? Bitbucket [supports Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-git-744723531.html), and you already have a Git repository…

Comment: hi Chris, you are correct i just realised there is no difference between both of them on: adding, pushing pulling. I am new on version control. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it needed a lot of time in the first place to synchronize. Now it runs smoothly: hg add . , hg commit -u user -m "text" , hg push – xbass540 23 hours ago